# Why isn't my vim extension working? I have fully uninstalled and reinstalled VS code and it's still broken :(

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscodevim

[broken vim gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/thBUC.gif)

- Reinstalling the extension
- Deleting the extension cache
- Checked that vim is enabled
- Restarted my computer multiple times
- Uninstalled vscode, deleted it's appdata
- Checked my settings
- Deleted the vim extension file

Please help :(

Answer (score 1):

I have since discovered that this extension breaks the Vim extension... https://github.com/blairjordan/codachi